# AngularJS Remember me functionality using JWT Auth

Tags: angularjs

I have developed an Spring Web application using Angular JS. For the current project the client side authentication is using Cookies.
After learning the advantage JWTs,
I rewrote the application Authentication using **JWTs(Json Web Token)**.

My concern is How to handle **"Rember Me" Functionality using JWT in AngularJS with out using Cookies funtionality or Laravel support**.

If anyone of you experts can share me suggestion or Sample code. It would be really helpful. I tried searching internet and failed to get an sample implementation to refer.

Thanks.

Comment: you can store your token inside localStorage

Comment: if you can share me some sample piece of code. Will be really helpful.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("jwt", angular.toJson(yourToken));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the option to store JWT at client side could be [window.localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) which stores data with no expiration date.
And after that, with each `$http` request(in Authentication header) you send this token to the server using Interceptor like following,

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('authInterceptor', ['$q', function ($q) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if (config.headers.skipAuthorization === false) {
                    var token = localStorage.getItem('authenticationToken');
                    if (token != null) {

                        config.headers.Authorization = token;
                    }
                }
                return config;
            },
            response: function (response) {
                if (response.headers("Authorization") != undefined || response.headers("Authorization") != '') {
                    localStorage.setItem('authenticationToken', response.headers("Authorization"));
                }
                return response;
            },
            responseError: function (rejection) {
                if (rejection.status === "401") {
                    localStorage.removeItem('authenticationToken');
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    } ]);

    angular.module('myApp').config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
    } ]);
```

And with each request where you want this token to be sent to the server, set `skipAuthorization:false` in header as,

```
$http({
....
headers:{skipAuthorization:false}
}).then(....)
```

Comment: But `JWT` has expiration in itself. We can store the token in `localStorage`, But when we send to the server, `JWT` would check the expiration. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, on the server, when we decode the JWT and validate it, it will give an error when the token has expired